# Updated Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 to 2016 OleDbDataAdapter is not working

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, oledbconnection

This code is used to convert CSV file to dataTable.

Before Updating to Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016, Our code works perfectly

`connection = new OleDbConnection(Config.connectionString);
connection.Open();
dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select  * from [" + fileName + "] ", connection);`

After we updated to Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016, Our logic can't proceed after connection.open().

I tried with top 10 it's work perfectly. `select top 10 * from [" + fileName + "]`

after this I tried with 1000, it also works perfectly.

But when I tried to top 10000 line, it failed.

Note: CSV file contain more than 80000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You use the term 'engine'; do you have a full installation of Office/Access 2016?

Comment: We installed  Access 2016, not Office 2016. Downloaded from : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Comment: Access 2016 doesn't include the runtime engine. Some versions of the install don't. They have a runtime engine install which is not the same as the runtime install.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the full Access license; do an import of the csv file manually using the features available in the ribbon.

At the end of this process, the wizard is going to open a prompt as to whether you wish to save those steps.  Save it with a meaningful name - and then you will be able to invoke that saved import easily.

This is not a fix of your old code - but rather a remake using the current technology.

To invoke the saved import is a simple docmd.runSavedImportExport